# How does compiler implement type aliasing?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, type-alias

Many languages support type alias. For example,

```
// C
typedef oldType newType
// go
type oldType = newType
```

How is it implemented internally?

Comment: Many ways really. It could be implemented as macros, or it could be propagated.

Comment: @Xilpex Can u please elaborate on both ways?

Answer (score 2):

In (very) general terms, each *type* corresponds to an instance of a compiler-internal `Type` object. (Whether that object has any analogue in the executable code produced by the compiler will vary by language.) A name will be aliased to a `Type` instance through a symbol table; if two names are aliases for the same *type*, their symbol table entries will (probably) refer to the same thing.

*Types* can generally be created from other *types* using type operators (such as array dimensions or structure/tuple aggregation), so the name of a *type* is not necessarily a simple identifier; it might also be some kind of expression. It's up to the language designer to decide whether two *types* which are built in the same way are the same *type* or not. For example, in C two array *types* with the same element *type* and the same dimension are the same *type*, whereas two `struct` *types* with the same member *types* are not the same *type*. Neither of these decisions was forced on the language designers, and other languages might have different conventions. (Again as an example, while C++ follows C by making two `struct` with the same members distinct *types*, two `std::tuple`s with the same template list are the same *type*.) These language design decisions will effect the way `Type` object equality is defined within the compiler, so it might also have an impact on how type aliases are implemented.